# Initializing an array, using some sort of loop that shoves stuff onto it, and returning it

Tags: ruby

I keep using a pattern in ruby over and over again.

Here are some examples:

```
 def get_row_numbers_for_id(id_to_search_for)
    @results = []
    (0...row_count).each do |row|
      get_row(row).css('td').each do |cell|
        @results << row unless row.nil? if (cell['id'] == id_to_search_for) && !(cell.to_html =~ /continued/i)
      end
    end
    @results
  end
```

And

```
def cell_content_array
    @cells = []
    @doc.css('td p span').each do |cell|
       @cells << cell.content
    end
    @cells
  end
```

I'm initializing an array, using some sort of loop that shoves stuff onto it, and returning it. I know there is a better way to do this.

What are some preferred Ruby ways to do this? All answers welcome.

Comment: A small thing, David: 'results' and 'cells' don't need to be instance variables; local variables would be within the scopes of the respective blocks.

Comment: what if you want to use an attr_acessor, reader or writer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is Array#map or Enumerable#collect.

The 2nd method can be written as

```
def cell_content_array
  @doc.css('td p span').map { |span| span.content }
end
```

Or, as we're simply extracting `content`, it can be further simplified to:

```
def cell_content_array
  @doc.css('td p span').map(&:content)
end
```

Your first method is pretty cryptic (`row unless row.nil? if ...` - what?), but if I understand it correctly, this should do

```
def get_row_numbers_for_id(id_to_search_for)
  rows.select do |row|
    cells = row.css("td##{id_to_search_for}") # find only cells with the right id
    cells.any? && cells.none? { |cell| cell.to_html =~ /continued/i }
  end
end
```

I'm assuming here, that you can extract a `rows` method that gives you all the relevant rows, so you can avoid the `(0...row_count)`. You can of course use `(0...row_count).map { ... }` instead, but it's nicer, I think, to place that bit of logic elsewhere, even if it is just one line.

Also, I don't know the rest of your code, but (provided `@doc` doesn't change after instantiation) you might want to use the `||=` operator in the `cell_content_array` method to cache the result to an instance variable. That way, it won't you don't need to run the CSS selector and mapping again on subsequent calls.

```
def cell_content_array
  @cell_content ||= @doc.css('td p span').map(&:content)
end
```